# Restart server without logout user session

Tags: java, jboss

I am using JBoss server. I have one problem with session. After logged in to the page again I restarted server. But user session is getting logged out. Again It redirects to login page. I need to allow user to see the webpage without logout.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the server, your login session information is lost. You need to persist it to avoid this.

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HAWebSessionsViaDatabasePersistence looks like exactly this.

Answer (score -1):

**When you restart the application server, all the sessions will be terminated, that is a normal thing, because sessions are kept in the memory to put it simply.**

If you want the user to continue on from his previous session, you will have to go through a lot of trouble such as re-creating the session objects and populate them with the data you somehow saved from last session, and a way to authenticate the user without the user entering his password again. That is probably the easy part which you can achieve by storing the session identifier in a cookie and keeping track of it in a database or text file, but re-creating the session itself exactly from where you left off might not be a good or even practical idea.

**Two options for storing and restoring the session:**

1) Save the data related to the session *(items in a shopping cart for instance)* in a database or a text file of some sort. (save it on the hard disk) This will prove very difficult, how difficult depending on the complexity of your site.

2) Save the users session data in a cookie along with the session identifier *(jsessionid)*. Again you will need to do some custom work, identifying these cookies and reading them. User can always get rid of cookies, or disable them etc.

**If you have a very simple web page that doesn't include any data other than the authentication, you simply want to see the previous page you were at, you can save a cookie in the client identifying the user and the page he was last at.**